# Merge one git branch to other

Tags: git, github, merge

There's a master remote branch, which has team1 as a remote branch. Master has had several commits since then. I have created a new branch team2 out of master and I am now trying to move all the commits in team1 to team2. I tried:

```
git rebase --onto master team1 team2
```

but to no avail. Can anyone help.

Pictoral representation:

```
a -> b -> c-> d (master)
|             |
|             k (team2)
e -> f -> g (team1)
```

I waana merge team1 commits e, f, g (there are many more actually) into team2, which is just a plain branch out of master. Cherry Picking is too hectic.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `git merge team1`?

Comment: Merge will apparently "merge" the two branches, which I do not want. Just want to "copy" the commits into the new branch.

Comment: There're around 70 commits in team1, hence cherry picking is too hectic.

Comment: Copying the commits is exactly what cherry-pick does.  I'm having a  hard time figuring out what concrete reason you have to avoid doing a merge with a git merge.  Copy the commits with cherry-pick, merge the histories with merge, or lose the history with squash-merge.

Comment: you can pass a range to cherry-pick

Comment: Why cant you just do a 

git rebase team1 , from team2 branch

If you do a git rebase team1 the commit hierarchy would become 
a ->e -> f -> g -> b -> c-> d ->k

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your team1 commits on team2 branch, you should do:

```
git rebase --onto team2 [a-hash] team1
```

because team2 is your target, and commit 'a' and team1 are delimiters of a group of commits you want to move.

I hope it helps :)